# Why is the same OpenGL function performing so differently in Clojure than in Java?

Tags: java, opengl, clojure

For fun I'm doing a simple OpenGL benchmark of various languages, and I just completed a Clojure implementation. It was running quite slow, however, so I decided to profile it with VisualVM, and I obtained some rather odd results. The following are snapshots from profiles of the Java and Clojure version respectively (both have identical rendering logic)

[image: Java profiling screencap]

[image: Clojure profiling screencap]

Note that glPopMatrix is the function taking up the most time in the Clojure implementation, by a significant margin, yet in the Java implementation glDrawArrays takes far more time. The code for the [Clojure version](https://github.com/logicchains/ParticleBench/blob/master/core.cj) is:

```
(defn render-pt [apt]
  (GL11/glPopMatrix)
  (GL11/glPushMatrix)
  (GL11/glTranslatef (:x apt) (:y apt) (- 0 (:z apt)) )
  (GL11/glScalef (* (:R apt) 2) (* (:R apt) 2) (* (:R apt) 2) )
  (GL11/glDrawArrays GL11/GL_QUADS 0 24)
  apt)
```

The function render-pt is mapped to an array of pt.

The code for the [Java version](https://github.com/logicchains/ParticleBench/blob/master/ParticleBench.java) is:

```
for (int i = minPt; i < numPts; i++) {
    Pt pt = Pts[i];
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glTranslatef(pt.X, pt.Y, -pt.Z);
    GL11.glScalef(pt.R * 2, pt.R * 2, pt.R * 2);
    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
}
```

The two functions seem the same to me; is there some mistake I'm making? Or am I reading the profile wrong?

Comment: EDIT: I thought that maybe, as your profile displayed evidence of `LazySeq`, that you didn't iterate on all the points ; but you do (with `dorun`). BTW, you shouldn't use def to declare local variables, use `let` instead.

Comment: @omiel Sorry about the code; it's a direct port of a Scheme implementation that reused global variables in an attempt to avoid allocation. I intend to clean it up once I've got the performance issues sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some differences between those functions:

`(:x apt)` always returns a boxed numeric value, since it is not type hinted. `pt.X` can likely return an unboxed numeric primitive, depending on the definition of `Pt`.

`(:x apt)` will do a hash lookup rather than the faster slot lookup that `pt.X` does (unless apt is a Clojure record, you don't show enough code for me to know which this is so I assume it is a hash-map).

Numeric literals are `Long` by default in Clojure, `Integer` by default in Java.

Comment: Yeah, but all of those should, as far as I can see, be adding more "self time", or some time in boxing/unboxing methods, while leaving the balance of time spent in drawArrays vs popMatrix basically the same as in Java. I'm quite puzzled by this one.

Comment: drawArrays / popMatrix may behave differently with Long vs. Integer / Double vs. Float inputs? Just a guess, and assuming that there are also Float literals (that in the Clojure code are Double literals).

Comment: Fascinating: when I change the following line, called only once in the program:

`(GL11/glFrustum -1  1  -1  1  1  1000)`

to the following:

`(GL11/glFrustum (int -1) (int 1) (int -1) (int 1) (int 1) (int 1000))`

then the framerate is increased by 15%! I didn't realise OpenGL was so sensitive to such things. I linked to the whole code in my question, by the way.